# Session management/monitoring in Apache mina

Tags: java, network-programming, apache-mina

Is there a (built in) way to monitor sessions in apache mina. I want to keep track of total session active whenever a session is created/closed.

I know i can do it by keeping references of all the incoming session in my IoHandlerAdapter and remove one when the session is closed. I am looking for a built in way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only monitor session create/close?

you need implement a IoServiceListener,call ioService.addListener.

whenever a session created/closed event happens ,your IoServiceListenerImplClass gets the event call

see

http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/apidocs/org/apache/mina/core/service/IoServiceListener.html

> http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/core/service/IoServiceListener.html

Comment: I want to get total no of sessions on session open/close. Sorry for any confusion.